# whats wrong in this code, and why charm is not imported? and error is

Tags: python

```
from charm.toolbox.integergroup import IntegerGroup
from charm.schemes.pkenc.pkenc_rsa import RSA_Enc, RSA_Sig
from charm.core.math.integer import integer, randomBits, random, randomPrime, isPrime, encode, decode, hashInt, bitsize, legendre, gcd, lcm, serialize, deserialize, int2Bytes, toInt
```

but it is giving error:

```
 from charm.schemes.pkenc.pkenc_rsa import RSA_Enc, RSA_Sig
  File "/home/ubuntu/pbc-0.5.14/Charm-Crypto-0.43/charm/schemes/pkenc/pkenc_rsa.py", line 13, in <module>
    from charm.core.math.integer import integer,isPrime,gcd,random,randomPrime,toInt
ImportError: cannot import name 'integer' from 'charm.core.math.integer' (unknown location)
```

Comment: Don't know about `charm`, but should it be `from charm.core.math import integer`?

Comment: tried but now it shows

Comment: from charm.core.math import integer, randomBits, random, randomPrime, isPrime, encode, decode, hashInt, bitsize, legendre, gcd, lcm, serialize, deserialize, int2Bytes, toInt                                                                       
ImportError: cannot import name 'randomBits' from 'charm.core.math' (/home/ubuntu/pbc-0.5.14/Charm-Crypto-0.43/charm/core/math/__init__.py)
another error

Comment: Edit the question. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].